# Does ng-repeat logic fire if its wrapped in a ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a ng-repeat that i want to show conditionally. If I wrap it with ng-if does that stop it from looping? Im trying to be careful about resources

Comment: Yes, if you use ng-if in a wrapper element

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` will include the DOM node only if the expression is valid. If it is not valid, then the `ng-repeat` will **not** fire, if it is within an `ng-if`

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Logically ng-repeat does not create any DOM element with empty data object. This is exactly the same case as wrapping it inside ng-if.
SO I think, from resource point of view your ng-if is absolutely redundant.

Comment: It could be that OP wants to not show the list, even though there _is_ data, because some other condition needs to be met? There's no right way to do this, but it's a possibility. This could be handled programatically as well.

Comment: Agree. 
Its important to know the Scenario to take this decision

Comment: Yes this correct,  sometimes i dont want to display anything.  I was just curious if angular skipped the loop based on ngif

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="expression">
  <!-- If expression is false, this block will be 'ignored' -->
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">

  </div>
  <!-- -->
</div>
```